# Importing photos into Photos app and overwriting previous import

Tags: mac, photos, photos.app

I have previously imported some pictures into the Photos app - however I found the files had become corrupt. Now I have gone back to the original source and used a more reliable drive to import them from. They now seem to not be corrupt.

Now I want to import them into the Photos app and overwrite the corrupt photos. It recognises that some have already been imported, meaning if I import all it will create duplicates which isn't what I want.

What is best to do?

Thanks

Comment: How about deletion from import folder? Ping me by @ankiiiiiii

Comment: True - could be worth a try. However it was imported a while ago.. didn’t know if there was a better way of doing it. I’ll have a look thanks.